# Can IntelliJ Subversion support cooperate with a TortoiseSVN checked out repository?

Tags: svn, intellij-idea, tortoisesvn

First, some context:

- Our Subversion server is using subversion v 1.6
- My TortoiseSVN client is v 1.9.5
- I have my Subversion repository checked out localy with TortoiseSVN, using subversion directory structure 1.6, to c:\JAVA

Now I would like to have IntelliJ use the same local repository, so that when I do a commit with IntelliJ, it is using the same local repository as TortoiseSVN.

Is this a weird thing to be looking for? Should I be using the repository differently, or is this easy/possible/common?

Comment: Do you experience any issues with the current setup?

Comment: I didn't manage to set it up like this yet :) So in a way, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use different Subversion client versions with a single working copy. If you have TortoiseSVN 1.9.x and IntelliJ can only use the Subversion 1.6 working copy format, you cannot use both clients with that working copy.

**NOTE** the version of Subversion running on the server is immaterial here as long as you're using a protocol other than `file:///` to access the repository.

If you initially checked out with TortoiseSVN, IntelliJ won't be able to read the working copy.

If you initially checked out with IntelliJ, TortoiseSVN will not work with it until you [intentionally upgrade the working copy](https://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.9.html#wc-upgrade) yourself.

Get IntelliJ upgraded to a version that supports a recent Subversion client library. The last 1.6.x release was nearly 4 years ago and is no longer supported. 1.9 is a year and a half old already.

Comment: This doesn't apply to the current IntelliJ IDEA versions since they can use command line TortoiseSVN client with whatever working copy version it supports (1.7+). Internal client library is used only for 1.6 and older working copies.

Comment: It's not my question.

Comment: Hey, OP here ;) Thanks for your answer. So, if I understand correctly, when I upgrade my working copy to 1.9, then it *is* possible to use different clients on the same working copy?

Comment: I upgraded my working repository to 1.8. When I now open one of the projects (checked out by Tortoise) in IntelliJ, it detects this is a subversion working copy, and can commit/update. So... seems to work fine this way!

Comment: @Wouter the only way that you can use a working copy upgrade to use multiple clients is if that new working copy version is supported by each client version you'e using. The upgrade didn't make the working copy magically universal. As an aside, there is no such thing in Subversion as a "working repository" - you have a *working copy*, and a *repository*. The terminology is important when communicating questions and answer.

Comment: Yeah, I was aware that I didn't know the correct way to call the thing... Hence I'm glad you understood what I was trying to do :) My clients both supported the latest Subversion version, so that part of the issue was covered.